# How to change some fragment in src img with jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have 2 div , i try to change src in div class big on click on preview,
    i just need to change the world 'big' by 'preview' , didn't find the good way

```
<div class="big"> <img src="image_big_123"> </div>
<div class="preview"> <img src="image_preview_642.jpg"> </div>

$('.preview').click(function(){ 
$('.big').attr('src', '?');
});

Result exepcted for this exemple , when you click on the div class preview , src image in div class big change for `<img src="image_preview_123">` ,
```

so only one world change in the src

Thx for any help
regards

Comment: Not clear! Please provide sample changed result!

Comment: The div doesn't have an `src` property. You need to target the image.

Comment: Use jQuery fancybox for this http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, use the replace function in javascript:

```
var preview2big = $('#preview img').attr('src').replace("_preview_", "_big_");
// in your code:
$('.big img').attr('src', $('#preview img').attr('src').replace("_preview_", "_big_") );
```

Its a bit unclear what you want, not really sure where you want the source from and what to replace=, the the principle remains the same.

A bit more to native JS (which I prefer and is also a bit easier to read):

```
$('.big img')[0].src = $('#preview img')[0].src.replace("_preview_", "_big_");
```

---

Or a bit more like a toggle (if you need that):

```
var newSrc = $('#preview img')[0].src;
var newSrc = newSrc.test(/_preview_/) ? newSrc.replace('_preview_', '_big_') : newSrc.replace('_big_', '_preview_');

$('.big img')[0].src = newSrc ; // this is preview if it was big ans vica versa
```

Comment: Don't forget to read *how* it works ;) Will help you better than a simple copy/paste :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a replace:

```
 var source = $('.big').find('img').attr('src'); //Get the current source
 var newsource = source.replace('big', 'preview'); // Replace the word 'big' with preview' 

 $(".big").find('img').attr('src', newsource); //Set the new source
```

So your final code would be:

```
<div class="big"> <img src="image_big_123"> </div>
<div class="preview"> <img src="image_preview_642.jpg"> </div>

$('.preview').click(function(){ 
   var source = $('.big').find('img').attr('src');
   var newsource = source.replace('big', 'preview');
   $(".big").find('img').attr('src', newsource);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work , output is : <div class="big"> img src="image_preview_123"> <img src="image_big_123"> </div>
<div class="preview"> <img src="image_preview_642.jpg"> </div>   basicly it just add an src but not replace

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$('.preview').click(function() {
   var prev = $('.big').children('img').attr('src').substring(10); 
   var newsrc = 'image_preview_'+prev;
  $('.big').children('img').attr('src', newsrc)
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5fvQf/)

Comment: With some doubt I've downvoted, for the following reason: Your code works in this exact situation, but if the string changes even 1 character, this stops working. IMO good solutions dont fix *exact* problems, but should be able to handle a bit more. Like the `replace()` methods in other answers

Comment: @Martijn I agree but since OP has asked in exact terms hence the exact answer. Had he used any thing like class may change or something i would have gone with something more generalized. No problem with the downvote though!

Comment: @albator Did you tried this? Please read the comment from Martjin on my answer and tell if this can be the case as well!